# Chrome Extensions and Cookies

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I've created a chrome extension and I'm trying to use it to allow a user to log into a system. I'm setting a cookie using chrome.cookies.set and then I'm trying to read it with PHP - but PHP never seems to see the cookie as being set. I've manually verified that the cookie exists but isset() always seems to be returning false.

```
chrome.cookies.set({"name":"username","url":"http://127.0.0.1","domain":null, "path": "/", "value":userName},function (cookie){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie));
  console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
  console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

That's how I'm setting the cookie and this is how I'm trying to fetch it with PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE["username"])){
        echo "Logged in";
    }
?>
```

Any ideas? This has had me stumped for a while now.

Comment: You might want to try and add an expirationdate to your cookie: `"expirationDate" :  `date + 1000000`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried set an expiration date like this `"expirationDate" : (new Date().getTime()/1000) + 3600` but PHP is still unable to see it as being set.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cookie api, but shouldn't your php code be `$_COOKIE["name"]`?

Comment: I don't think so, that piece of code is setting the cookie's name to be "username". I tried changing the php to `$_COOKIE["name"]` anyway, with no joy. I've even tried setting the cookie from a separate login.php script - the cookie is being created because I can see it with chrome, but for some reason PHP simply cannot validate it. At first I thought it was a problem with the scope of the extension but it should definitely work from a separate php file surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never did fix the exact problem I was having with the cookies, I've decided to use OAuth for authentication instead.